# How do I make an order by amount of score in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, visual-studio-2017

Im trying to create an MS Access query to display scores of two class. Class A and Class B. Im trying to select top 3 of the students with highest total scores, but Im not sure how to do it. Right now Im ordering it by their NIM (Stands for ID of student)

I've tried replacing the order by line with other such as SUM(xx) / sum(xx) DESC but it doesnt work. Could you help me point it out?

```vb
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            m.NIM                                                                                         AS NIM
          , m.Nama_Mhs                                                                                    AS Nama_Mhs
          , n.Kelas                                                                                       AS Kelas
          , n.Tahun_Akademik                                                                              AS Tahun
          , SUM(k.SKS         * Switch(n.Huruf ='A', 4, n.Huruf='B', 3, n.Huruf='C', 2, n.Huruf='D', 1, TRUE, 0)) AS NilaiTotalA
          , ROUND(NilaiTotalA / SUM(k.SKS), 2)                                                                    As NilaiIPKA
        FROM
            (Master_Mahasiswa m
            INNER JOIN
                Nilai n
                On
                    m.NIM=n.NIM)
            INNER JOIN
                Master_MK k
                On
                    k.Kode_MK=n.Kode_MK
        GROUP BY
            m.NIM
          , m.Nama_Mhs
          , n.Kelas
          , n.Tahun_Akademik
        HAVING
            n.Kelas ='IK - 2A'
        ORDER BY
            SUM(k.SKS*SWITCH(n.Huruf='A', 4, n.Huruf='B', 3, n.Huruf='C', 2, n.Huruf='D', 1, TRUE, 0))/SUM(k.SKS) DESC
    )
    sub1
    RIGHT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                TOP 3 m.NIM                                                                                 AS NIM
              , m.Nama_Mhs                                                                                  AS Nama_Mhs
              , n.Kelas                                                                                     AS Kelas
              , n.Tahun_Akademik                                                                            AS Tahun
              , SUM(k.SKS        *SWITCH(n.Huruf='A', 4, n.Huruf='B', 3, n.Huruf='C', 2, n.Huruf='D', 1, TRUE, 0)) AS NilaiTotalB
              , ROUND(NilaiTotalB/SUM(k.SKS), 2)                                                                   AS NilaiIPKB
            FROM
                (Master_Mahasiswa m
                INNER JOIN
                    Nilai n
                    ON
                        m.NIM=n.NIM)
                INNER JOIN
                    Master_MK k
                    ON
                        k.Kode_MK=n.Kode_MK
            GROUP BY
                m.NIM
              , m.Nama_Mhs
              , n.Kelas
              , n.Tahun_Akademik
            HAVING
                n.Kelas ='IK - 2B'
            ORDER BY
                SUM(k.SKS*SWITCH(n.Huruf='A', 4, n.Huruf='B', 3, n.Huruf='C', 2, n.Huruf='D', 1, TRUE, 0))/SUM(k.SKS) DESC
        )
        sub2
        ON
            MID(sub1.NIM, 11, 2)=MID(sub2.NIM, 11, 2)
ORDER BY
    sub2.NIM
UNION
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 3 m.NIM                                                                                   As NIM
          , m.Nama_Mhs                                                                                    As Nama_Mhs
          , n.Kelas                                                                                       As Kelas
          , n.Tahun_Akademik                                                                              As Tahun
          , SUM(k.SKS        * Switch(n.Huruf ='A', 4, n.Huruf='B', 3, n.Huruf='C', 2, n.Huruf='D', 1, TRUE, 0)) AS NilaiTotalA
          , ROUND(NilaiTotalA/SUM(k.SKS), 2)                                                                     AS NilaiIPKA
        FROM
            (Master_Mahasiswa m
            INNER JOIN
                Nilai n
                ON
                    m.NIM=n.NIM)
            INNER JOIN
                Master_MK k
                ON
                    k.Kode_MK=n.Kode_MK
        GROUP BY
            m.NIM
          , m.Nama_Mhs
          , n.Kelas
          , n.Tahun_Akademik
        HAVING
            n.Kelas ='IK - 2A'
        ORDER BY
            SUM(k.SKS*SWITCH(n.Huruf='A', 4, n.Huruf='B', 3, n.Huruf='C', 2, n.Huruf='D', 1, TRUE, 0))/SUM(k.SKS) DESC
    )
    sub1
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                m.NIM                                                                                       AS NIM
              , m.Nama_Mhs                                                                                  AS Nama_Mhs
              , n.Kelas                                                                                     AS Kelas
              , n.Tahun_Akademik                                                                            AS Tahun
              , SUM(k.SKS        *SWITCH(n.Huruf='A', 4, n.Huruf='B', 3, n.Huruf='C', 2, n.Huruf='D', 1, TRUE, 0)) AS NilaiTotalB
              , ROUND(NilaiTotalB/SUM(k.SKS), 2)                                                                   AS NilaiIPKB
            FROM
                (Master_Mahasiswa m
                INNER JOIN
                    Nilai n
                    ON
                        m.NIM=n.NIM)
                INNER JOIN
                    Master_MK k
                    ON
                        k.Kode_MK=n.Kode_MK
            GROUP BY
                m.NIM
              , m.Nama_Mhs
              , n.Kelas
              , n.Tahun_Akademik
            HAVING
                n.Kelas ='IK - 2B'
            ORDER BY
                SUM(k.SKS*SWITCH(n.Huruf='A', 4, n.Huruf='B', 3, n.Huruf='C', 2, n.Huruf='D', 1, TRUE, 0))/SUM(k.SKS) DESC
        )
        sub2
        ON
            MID(sub1.NIM, 11, 2)=MID(sub2.NIM, 11, 2)
ORDER BY
    sub2.NIM
;
```

Im trying to make it order by "NilaiIPKA"(Basically an average score of class A)  and "NilaiIPKB"(Average score of class b). How do I do it? Could someone help with the query please? I need to finish this soon.. Thanks

Sorry if the code is a little bit messy, I dont know how to really arange it here. This is a screenshot of my MS Access query https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFxht.jpg

Comment: Anyone please? Im still not used to this and I have to done this task within at least 2 or 3 hours.. even now Im still trying while being clueless

Comment: Can you provide information about the tables you're trying to perform this operation on? It's quite difficult to understand the issue without knowing the data structure to begin with. Also you might want to consider removing the picture of your current results for a redacted version if that's actually some real data and not just stubs. I imagine posting pictures of students class results would be considered a data breach by most organisations.

Comment: Oh Im actually not using real data. It's just for test. I can provide you anything about the tables. What do you need?

Comment: so do you basically want the top 3 from each group ordered by some factor? liek whats the ideal output

Comment: I've removed it, cause some of the names are real names. But the rest are just made up

Comment: Yes top 3 from each group.. but Im confused how to do it

Comment: It would be good to know what the tables are called, what fields they have, and if it's not immedietely obvious then any relationships between them.

Comment: Im trying to make this chart display top 3. If possbile its like ID 01 of class A and ID 01 of class B would put together, blue and yellow bar https://imgur.com/WJ7Q1r9

Comment: This is basically where the scores are stored https://imgur.com/ohJPJS9
Its something like "there is 8 courses, every score of each course for each student is stored there according to their ID (NIM)"

Comment: NIM(ID), Kelas(Class), Semester(Semester), Tahun_Akademik(Academic Year), Kode_MK(Basically courses code), N1(Score 1), N2(Score 2), N3(Score 3), Nilai Akhir(Final Score), Huruf(Scores but in alphabet, A,B,C,D,E)

Comment: Eh basically top 3 ordered by the highest amount of NilaiIPKA and NilaiIPKB https://imgur.com/F4mqcTM, then display it on the chart that would look like this https://imgur.com/f45lM0s, check out the "Chart IPK". The NilaiIPKA would be the blue bar and NilaiIPKB would be yellow. Thats the output